# What does apt's "failed in buffer_write(fd)" error message mean?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, aptitude, apt

I have a server and am trying to do an apt-get upgrade, and get the following error message. What does it mean?

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-ubuntu-modules-2.6.24-27-generic_2.6.24-27.45_i386.deb: failed in buffer_write(fd) (10, ret=-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your disk (or /var/apt partition) is full, try to free some space.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem but this is my df -m output :

/dev/mapper/xor-root       322       267        39  88% /
tmpfs                     1004         1      1004   1% /lib/init/rw
udev                        10         1        10   9% /dev
tmpfs                     1004         0      1004   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                  228        19       198   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/xor-home     60884     22193     35599  39% /home
/dev/mapper/xor-tmp        368        11       339   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/xor-usr       4694      2687      1769  61% /usr
/dev/mapper/xor-var       2816       351      2322  14% /var